# Using a variable when setting a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a variable loop to check a column for a value. If that column has a value I want to use that variable to set a range B & variable to F33.

So sArea is the variable

how do I replace this:

```
Sheets("DEVELOPMENT CONTROL").ScrollArea = "B1:F33"
```

To something like this:

```
Sheets("DEVELOPMENT CONTROL").ScrollArea = "B & sArea : G38"
```

which doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Sheets("DEVELOPMENT CONTROL").ScrollArea = "B" & sArea & ":G38"
```

You need to pass sArea as a variable instead of text, like above.